# autocomplete in Thunderbird

Tags: email, thunderbird, autocomplete

an old and unsupported email address of mine keeps appearing in From and I dont always check which one is there so am sending people emails from this email by mistake. This email is NOT in Collected Addresses so I cant delete it from there. Can you help me?
This email is for the Local Folder, that is the first one I had. Under profile, only Local Folder is there.

Answer (score 0):

Open the menu on the top right (the three horizontal bars), hover over `preferences` and then select `Account settings`. On the left side down at the bottom you'll find `Outgoing Servers`. Select that and then pick your preferred email on the right and click `Set Default`.

You can also remove the unused old email from there.